# When do changes to wp-config.php take effect?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to enable debugging on a WordPress site to debug a plugin.  I read about the [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) setting and I added the following to my `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

My understanding is that I should see a `debug.log` file in my `wp-content` directory.  I haven't seen anything yet, but I don't know if that is because there aren't any errors that have been logged, or if something needs to be restarted for these settings to take effect.  So my question is when are the `wp-config.php` settings read and do I need to restart any services to make changes take effect.

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart anything for the changes to apply since Wordpress is instantiated from the ground up on each request. This might not be the case if you are using APC or a similar opcode caching system however (I'm not very knowledgable in that area).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

"Changes" to `wp-config.php` take place right away when edited by FTP or via the shell, because that file is accessed each time any page is generated and output by WordPress. No reboot of the server is needed; just do a load or a refresh of any front or backend page of the WordPress site.

Do something to trigger a php error, like removing a bracket from a php function in `header.php` of the theme and see if that gets logged in `debug.log`. Check for the error in `debug.log` in `wp-content`.

If the file doesn't exist, there may be permission problems and WordPress couldn't create the file. So add a plain text file (with the correct text encoding for your system; it's best to use the FTP client to create a few file) and title it `debug.log`. If you create the file locally and upload it, give it at least 755 permissions, but 644 is safer. Then invoke a php error again and see if it gets logged.